# WCF service could not be activated

Tags: wcf, x509certificate

I am having problem with my WCF (which has client and server certificates)

**Exception:**

> System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException:
>   The requested service,
>   'http://localhost/CustomerServiceSite/Customer.svc'
>   could not be activated. See the
>   server's diagnostic trace logs for
>   more information..

**Error Stack trace:**

> DoNegotiation(TimeSpan timeout)
>   System.ServiceModel.Security.SspiNegotiationTokenProvider.OnOpen(TimeSpan
>   timeout)
>   System.ServiceModel.Security.TlsnegoTokenProvider.OnOpen(TimeSpan
>   timeout)
>   System.ServiceModel.Security.WrapperSecurityCommunicationObject.OnOpen(TimeSpan
>   timeout)
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan
>   timeout)
>   System.ServiceModel.Security.CommunicationObjectSecurityTokenProvider.Open(TimeSpan
>   timeout)
>   System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityUtils.OpenTokenProviderIfRequired(SecurityTokenProvider
>   tokenProvider, TimeSpan timeout)
>   System.ServiceModel.Security.SymmetricSecurityProtocol.OnOpen(TimeSpan
>   timeout)
>   System.ServiceModel.Security.WrapperSecurityCommunicationObject.OnOpen(TimeSpan
>   timeout)
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan
>   timeout) OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan
>   timeout)
>   System.ServiceModel.Security.SecuritySessionSecurityTokenProvider.DoOperation(SecuritySessionOperation
>   operation, EndpointAddress target, Uri
>   via, SecurityToken currentToken,
>   TimeSpan timeout)
>   System.ServiceModel.Security.SecuritySessionSecurityTokenProvider.GetTokenCore(TimeSpan
>   timeout)
>   System.IdentityModel.Selectors.SecurityTokenProvider.GetToken(TimeSpan
>   timeout)
>   ClientSecuritySessionChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan
>   timeout)
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan
>   timeout)
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan
>   timeout)
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan
>   timeout)
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type)
>   System.ServiceModel.ICommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan
>   timeout)
>   System.ServiceModel.ICommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan
>   timeout) Open()

**Dignostics settings** (inside system.serviceModel)

```
<diagnostics>
  <messageLogging logEntireMessage="true" logMalformedMessages="true"
  logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true" logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" />
</diagnostics>
```

Where can I see diagnostics errors? Someone know what could be the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That configuration won't be sufficient for logging those error messages.

What you need is two-fold - first the part inside `<system.serviceModel>` that you already have, to instruct WCF to do logging.

But you also need a second part - inside `<system.diagnostics>` - to define where to log that information to! Something like this:

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
        <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging" switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing">
           <listeners>
             <add name="messages"
             type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
             initializeData="c:\logs\messages.svclog" />
          </listeners>
        </source>
    </sources>
    <trace autoflush="true" />
</system.diagnostics>
```

There are a few different log listeners defined in the `System.Diagnostics` namespace - this one here will be logging the information to a XML-based `*.svclog` file, which you can then view and analyze using the [Service Trace Viewer Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023.aspx).

Read more about [Configure Message Logging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730064.aspx) on MSDN.

Answer (score 2):

Just look in the Applications event log with the Event Viewer application.